# Minimal subrepresentation of the Weyl group

Tags: rt.representation-theory, weyl-group, induced-representations

**Background**

I want to generalize Theorem 3.2.1 in

Dat, J., Orlik, S., & Rapoport, M. (2010). Period Domains over Finite and p-adic Fields (Cambridge Tracts in Mathematics). Cambridge: Cambridge University Press. doi:10.1017/CBO9780511762482

to more general reductive groups than just the general linear group.

**My question**

Let $W$ be a Weyl group of type $B_n$ or $D_n$, and let $S\subset W$ be the set of simple reflections.

For $I\subset S$, define $W_I\subset W$ to be the subgroup generated by the elements in $I$. We can consider the $W$-representation $\text{Ind}^W_{W_I}(\textbf{1})$ induced from the trivial representation on $W_I$.

I am interested in the existence of an irreducible subrepresentation $\chi_I\subset \text{Ind}^W_{W_I}(\textbf{1})$ such that $\chi_I$ is "minimal" in some sense.
Explicitly, I want $\chi_I$ to satisfy a condition $$\chi_I\subset \text{Ind}^W_{W_J}(\textbf{1})\leftrightarrow J\subset I$$ where the RHS is taken up to conjugation.

Does such an $\chi_I$ exist?

Any help is appreciated! If anyone knows of a reference generalizing the abovementioned theorem I would also be very happy.